# Is this Proposition equivalent to the Class Equation or does it bring some more information?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory

This post cumulates and actually supersedes [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3072598/given-a-finite-group-does-this-equation-involving-groups-order-a-partition-of?noredirect=1#comment6335730_3072598) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3075073/consistency-with-the-class-equation), both *mine* and *unanswered*. Therefore, I'd have no objections if they were both deleted.

---

Is the following Proposition equivalent to the Class Equation (see the Remark at the end) or does it bring some more information?

***Proposition***

Let $G$ be a finite group or order $n$ and *trivial center*, and $C_G(a)$ denote the centralizer of $a$ in $G$. Then:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{a \in G \setminus \lbrace e \rbrace}[G:C_G(a)]=\sum_{\substack{\lambda_i \in \lambda(n-1)\\ \lambda_i>1}}\lambda_i^2\end{equation}

where $\lambda(n-1)$ is a partition of the integer $n-1$. Besides:

\begin{equation}
n(n-1)=\sum_{a \in G \setminus \lbrace e \rbrace}\delta(\Lambda)_a|C_G(a)|
\end{equation}

where $\delta(\Lambda)$ is a $(n-1)$-summands partition of the integer $\Lambda:=\sum_{\substack{\lambda_i \in \lambda(n-1)\\ \lambda_i>1}}\lambda_i^2$.

***Proof***

Let's define the collections $F_a:=(\varphi_g(a))_{g\in G}$, where $\varphi_g(a):=g^{-1}ag$, and denote by $\tilde F_a$ the set composed of the *distinct* elements of $F_a$. We have:

1. $\forall a \in G, a \in \tilde F_a$; then, $\tilde F_a \ne \emptyset$;
2. $\forall a \in G, |F_a|=n$;
3. $\tilde F_e=\lbrace e \rbrace$;
4. $Z(G)=\lbrace e \rbrace \Rightarrow |\tilde F_a|>1, \forall a \in G, a \ne e$;
5. $F_a=(\varphi_{g}(a))_{g \in C_G(a)} \cup (\varphi_{g}(a))_{g \in ∁_G(C_G(a))}=(a,a,...,a) \cup (\varphi_{g}(a))_{g \in ∁_G(C_G(a))}$, with $|(a,a,...,a)|=|C_G(a)|$;
6. given $a,b \in G, b \ne a$, it is $\tilde F_b=\tilde F_a \Leftrightarrow b \in \tilde F_a$;
7. the collection $(\varphi_{g}(a))_{g \in ∁_G(C_G(a))}$ contains as many *copies* of *each* element $b \in \tilde F_a \setminus \lbrace a \rbrace$ as is the cardinality of the set $\tilde{\mathcal{F}}_b^{(a)}:=\lbrace g \in \complement_G(C_G(a))|\varphi_g(a)=b \rbrace$, *minus* $1$.

We may also think of a $n \times n$ "matrix" such that, given $a \in G$, the "$a$-th" row is made of the elements of the set $\lbrace \varphi_a(g)|g \in G \rbrace$ and the "$a$-th" column is made of the elements of the collection $F_a=(\varphi_g(a))_{g \in G}$. According to this "picture", we have that:

- by 3 and 4, there's one and only one column with *all* the entries equal to each other (all $e$);
- by 5, the "$a$-th" column contains as many *copies* of $a$ as the order of $C_G(a)$, *minus* $1$;
- by 6 and 7, there are $|\tilde F_a|$ columns with the same, differently permuted, $|\tilde F_a|$ distinct elements (included the "index" $a$); each of these columns has as many *copies* of each element $b$ of $\tilde F_a \setminus \lbrace a \rbrace$ as is the integer $|\tilde{\mathcal{F}}_b^{(a)}|-1$.

Now, $\tilde{\mathcal{F}}_b^{(a)}=\emptyset \Leftrightarrow b \notin \tilde F_a$, and then $b \in \tilde F_a \Rightarrow \tilde{\mathcal{F}}_b^{(a)} \ne \emptyset \Rightarrow |\tilde{\mathcal{F}}_b^{(a)}|=|C_G(a)|$, since the sets $\tilde{\mathcal{F}}_b^{(a)}$ are precisely the right cosets of $C_G(a)$ in $G$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3071838/how-many-g-in-a-finite-group-are-such-that-b-g-1ag-for-given-a-ne-b-in/3071918#3071918) for the proof).

By summing on all the columns, we have that a partition $\lambda(n-1)$ of the integer $n-1$ exists such that:

\begin{align}
n^2& = n+\sum_{\substack{\lambda_i \in \lambda(n-1)\\ \lambda_i>1}}\lambda_i^2+\sum_{a \in G \setminus \lbrace e \rbrace}(|C_G(a)|-1)+\sum_{a \in G \setminus \lbrace e \rbrace}\sum_{b \in \tilde F_a \setminus \lbrace a \rbrace}(|\tilde{\mathcal{F}}_b^{(a)}|-1)=\\&=n+\sum_{\substack{\lambda_i \in \lambda(n-1)\\ \lambda_i>1}}\lambda_i^2+\sum_{a \in G \setminus \lbrace e \rbrace}(|C_G(a)|-1)+\sum_{a \in G \setminus \lbrace e \rbrace}|\tilde F_a \setminus \lbrace a \rbrace|(|C_G(a)|-1)=\\&=n+\sum_{\substack{\lambda_i \in \lambda(n-1)\\ \lambda_i>1}}\lambda_i^2+\sum_{a \in G \setminus \lbrace e \rbrace}(|\tilde F_a \setminus \lbrace a \rbrace|+1)(|C_G(a)|-1)
\end{align}

But, $$\sum_{a \in G \setminus \lbrace e \rbrace}(|\tilde F_a \setminus \lbrace a \rbrace|+1)=\sum_{\substack{\lambda_i \in \lambda(n-1)\\ \lambda_i>1}}\lambda_i^2$$

so, if we define $\delta_a:=|\tilde F_a \setminus \lbrace a \rbrace|+1$, we get:

\begin{equation}
n(n-1) = \sum_{\substack{\lambda_i \in \lambda(n-1)\\ \lambda_i>1}}\lambda_i^2+\sum_{a \in G \setminus \lbrace e \rbrace}\delta_a(|C_G(a)|-1)
\end{equation}

with $$\sum_{a \in G \setminus \lbrace e \rbrace}\delta_a=\sum_{\substack{\lambda_i \in \lambda(n-1)\\ \lambda_i>1}}\lambda_i^2$$

and then

\begin{equation}
n(n-1)=\sum_{a \in G \setminus \lbrace e \rbrace}\delta(\Lambda)_a|C_G(a)|
\end{equation}

where $\delta(\Lambda)$ is a $(n-1)$-summands partition of $\Lambda:=\sum_{\substack{\lambda_i \in \lambda(n-1)\\ \lambda_i>1}}\lambda_i^2$.

Now, we have seen that each $a \in G$, $a \ne e$, gives rise to the collection $F_a$ made of:

- $|\tilde F_a|$ distinct elements of $G$, included $a$;
- $|C_G(a)|-1$ copies of $a$;
- $|\mathcal{F}_b^{(a)}|-1=|C_G(a)|-1$ copies of $b$, for each $b \in \tilde F_a \setminus \lbrace a \rbrace$.

Then, 
\begin{align}
n=&|\tilde F_a|+|C_G(a)|-1+(|C_G(a)|-1)(|\tilde F_a|-1)=\\=&|\tilde F_a|+|C_G(a)|-1+|C_G(a)||\tilde F_a|-|C_G(a)|-|\tilde F_a|+1=\\=&|C_G(a)||\tilde F_a|
\end{align}

so $|\tilde F_a|=[G:C_G(a)]$, and finally (reminding that $\delta_a:=|\tilde F_a \setminus \lbrace a \rbrace|+1=$ $|\tilde F_a|$) $$\sum_{a \in G \setminus \lbrace e \rbrace}[G:C_G(a)]=\sum_{\substack{\lambda_i \in \lambda(n-1)\\ \lambda_i>1}}\lambda_i^2$$
$\blacksquare$

---

### Remark

Let's denote by $|\lambda(n-1)|$ the number of summands in the partition $\lambda(n-1)$. There are $|\lambda(n-1)|$ sets $\tilde F_{b_j}$ such that $G \setminus \lbrace e \rbrace = \underset{j=1}{\overset{|\lambda(n-1)|}{\bigcup}}\tilde F_{b_j}$ and $\tilde F_{b_i}\cap\tilde F_{b_j}=\emptyset, \forall i,j=1,\dots,|\lambda(n-1)|$. Call $B:=\lbrace b_1,\dots,b_{|\lambda(n-1)|}\rbrace$. Then, $\sum_{b_j \in B}[G:C_G(b_j)]=\sum_{b_j \in B}|\tilde F_{b_j}|=n-1$, whence: $$n=1+\sum_{b_j \in B}[G:C_G(b_j)]$$
This is the Class Equation for groups with trivial center.

Comment: I don’t understand why in (7) is *minus* $1$, because for each element $b \in \tilde F_a \setminus \lbrace a \rbrace$ in the collection $(\varphi_{g}(a))_{g \in ∁_G(C_G(a))}$ are equal to $b$ exactly these elements $\varphi_{g}(a)$ for which $g\in\tilde{\mathcal{F}}_b^{(a)}$, right? Or we consider one of these element as a *true* $b$ and other as its copies?

Comment: As you argued, there I meant to count just the copies. The "true" one is already accounted for in term coming from 6.