# Irreducible Representations of $S4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

so ive been trying to get all the irreducible representations of $S4$ and their dimensions, I know that there are 5 because they are 5 conjugacy classes in $S4$ and that 2 have dimension 1 because $S4/[S4,S4] \cong \mathbb{Z}_2$, but i need to find the dimension of the other tree, where i tried using the formula $|S4|=1+1+n_3^2+n_4^2+n_5^2$. My question is is there any other way to find out the dimensions of these representations without having to find the right 3 numbers that squared give 22? Is there another way to do it ? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: $S_4$ acts on a $4$-dimensional vector space by permuting basis vectors. Can you check if this is irreducible, or if not how it decomposes? Be careful to consider special cases on the characteristic of the field.

Comment: I'd consider the Specht modules.

Comment: @AdamHiggins Seeing as he says there are $5$, he is presumably working over the complex numbers. But your suggestion is still a great place to start since it finds one of the numbers.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft unless I am mistaken, there are 5 over any  algebraically closed field that doesn’t have characteristic 2 or 3?

Comment: @AdamHiggins Sure, and in those cases you don't need to worry about considerations of characteristic (but the way it is phrased makes me expect this is just for complex numbers).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Fair point. I find studying this particular representation to be a enlightening example which demonstrates why reliance on characteristic is such a common occurrence in representation theory. But fair enough. You’re probably right about the specifics of the question, but it can’t hurt to widen one’s consideration slightly.

Comment: I expected $S_4$ to have just one singleton, not two, as it has trivial center. Where am I wrong?

Comment: @Luca the equation written is not the class equation, so it is not related to the center.

Comment: @Luca We explicitly know two one-dimensional representations: the trivial representation and the sign representation.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I know too little about representations to go farther on this discussion. I was simply biased by a similar "sum of squares" of summads to $n-1$ appearing in my post here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3077681/is-this-proposition-equivalent-to-the-class-equation-or-does-it-bring-some-more?noredirect=1#comment6367015_3077681